# Simple harmonic question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator, spring

> consider a spring with a block of mass $m$ and spring constant $k$ that is inside a lift.  the cable breaks and the lift falls freely. Show that the block now executes a simple harmonic motion of amplitude $mg/k$.

when i saw the solution the answers used frame of reference as the elevator . why is this so?  can we use the frame of reference of an observer standing on the ground?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. While your question does ask about a specific physics concept, homework questions asked here usually require presentation of work or the thought process to not be considered as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're measuring the position of the block from the ground you're going to get something like this:

[image: Ground frame]

That is the average position of the block (and elevator) is going to change quadratically with time as the lift accelerates downwards. The oscillation of the block is superimposed on this quadratic. There's no reason why you can't analyse the motion in this frame, but it obviously isn't simple harmonic motion because it's the sum of SHM plus a quadratic.

When you choose the elevator as your reference frame you are in effect subtracting off the quadratic part of the motion (the red line) to leave just the SHM. That's why in the reference frame of the lift the motion is SHM.